# Как изменить стандартный внешний вид desktop приложения, который предоставляет Windows?

Tags: javascript, electron

Пишется desctop приложение с использованием Electron + JS, необходимо поменять внешний вид приложения, который предоставляет Windows, а именно рамку, кнопочки: закрыть, на весь экран, свернуть и т.п. Что может помочь в решении этой проблемы?

Comment: [new BrowserWindow({frame: false})](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window#создание-безрамного-окна)

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь вытекла другая проблема: на BrowserWindow присабачил BrowserView, которая в планах выступает в качестве кастомной рамки вместо отключенной от винды. Все перелопатил, но не могу понять какой опцией или мб методом можно сделать так, чтобы все приложение можно было перетаскивать по экрану дергая в любой точке области BrowserView.

Comment: я только что [body style="-webkit-app-region: drag"](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window#%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-drag-and-drop), у меня перетаскиваетсяя в том числе и за BrowserView.

Comment: Добавляю это к документу BrowserView и ничего не работает, а при добавлении к BrowserWindow перетаскивание работает вообще за любую часть программы, а мне нужно только при нажатии и перетягивании по BrowserView

Comment: видимо View привязан к window. Наверное только если писать самому какой-то обработчик и передвигать с помощью [setBounds](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetboundsbounds-animate)